# Orthogonal Codes for Band Limited Channel

Tags: digital-communications, orthogonal-signals

In this question [orthogonal family and pulse shaping filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/55568/orthogonal-family-and-pulse-shaping-filter/64783?noredirect=1#comment131861_64783) the user asked about possible loss of orthogonality of orthogonal codes due to the use of raised cosine pulse shaping and I showed as an answer how a correlation between codes can occur due to pulse shaping.

This leads me to the question of orthogonal codes for use in band limited channels. Are there such codes that exist that both provide band limiting (similar to what raised-cosine pulse shaping provides) and guarantee complete orthogonality between the band limited waveforms themselves? Here orthogonal means the inner product (dot product) between the waveforms is zero.

In particular as a matter of technical interest I am interested in solutions that mathematically result in 0 (such as Walsh codes prior to any pulse shaping when properly synchronized). If this does not exist then the solution that provides a complete family of codes and has the lowest relative cross correlation (relative to other solutions of the same code size) will be selected as the best answer. As I found in the linked question, testing just two samples of the complete code family are not sufficient to conclude.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: let $p_k(t) = p(t-kT)$ an orthonormal set for integer $k$. You want conditions for $s_1(t) = \sum_n a_n p_n(t)$ and $s_2(t) = \sum_m b_m p_m(t)$ to be orthogonal?

Comment: One more question: why do you need the pulse-shaped signals $s_1(t)$ and $s_2(t)$ to be orthogonal? I think you should be able to recover the orthogonal code by matched-filtering each individual pulse, and check orthogonality of the recovered code afterwards.

Comment: That matched filter recovery is correlation and if you lose orthogonality it reduces the distance between codes and therefore your ability to do what you suggest. The performance difference is similar to the difference between soft decision and hard decision decoding, or predection and postdetection filtering etc. More specifically consider correlating before the decisions and after the decisions and for CDMA operation we are often operating in very low pre-correlation SNR conditions but we may be far away from the transmitter but still interested in band limiting for terrestrial applications.

Comment: So to your first question it is not the ability of the demodulated code set to be orthogonal but the full waveform as received for purpose of code separation after the matched filter.

Comment: Right, so you want the dot product $s_1(t) \cdot s_2(t) =0$, right?

Comment: +1 for the interesting problem presented. But is there any advantage in s1 and s2 being orthogonal? They will be orthogonal only if the sequence used to generate them are orthogonal, correct? And there is no guarantee we will always transmit orthogonal sequences unless we use spreading technique. How much advantage does having s1/s2 being orthogonal present over the underlying spreading sequence being orthogonal? I would love to understand it. Good question.

Comment: @jithin Consider that the underlying spreading sequence can be the family of orthogonal codes. Each symbol represents the set of data being simultaneously transmitted within each time interval (CDMA), so if we have a family of 64 codes (symbols) for example we can transmit 6 data bits per symbol. A broadcast from one Tx to multiple Rx would be an example application but even with that there are other factors in the channel itself that will also decorrelate the symbols.

Comment: @MBaz Yes the dot product of $s_1(t)$ and $s_2(t)$ should be zero considering the over-sampled waveform (not just the correct sampling location).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_k(t) = p(t-kT)$ an orthonormal signal set for integer $k$ and $T>0$. In other words, we require that:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(t-\alpha T) p(t - \beta T) dt = 
\begin{cases}0, \text{  if $\alpha \neq \beta$}\\1, \text{  if $\alpha = \beta$}\end{cases} $$
The most common example of an orthonormal set is the [square-root raised cosine pulse (SRRC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-raised-cosine_filter). After matched filtering, SRRC pulses become raised-cosine pulses, which have zero ISI.

Let $s_1(t) = \sum_m a_m p_m(t)$ and $s_2(t) = \sum_m b_m p_m(t)$, where $a_m, b_m \in \mathbb{R}$ (the result below can be easily extended to the complex case).

The dot product $s_1(t) \cdot s_2(t)$ is

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty s_1(t) s_2(t) dt &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \sum_m a_m p_m(t) \right) \left( \sum_m b_m p_m(t) \right) dt \\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sum_m a_m b_m p^2_m(t) dt \\
&=& \sum_m a_m b_m.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
In the second step, I used the fact that $\int p_m(t) p_n(t) dt = 0$ if $m \neq n$. In the third step, I used the fact that $p(t)$ has energy equal to one.

Then, the dot product is zero only when $\sum_m a_m b_m = 0$. Note that the assumptions stated above about $p(t)$ are crucial. If you use a pulse that does not meet these conditions (for example, a raised-cosine pulse instead of square-root RC), then the dot product $s_1(t) \cdot s_2(t)$ will not be zero even if the sequenes $a_m,b_m$ are orthogonal.

Comment: Dan, This results contradicts your findings; I wonder if you can find where the error is.

Comment: Dan: it seems like you didn't use unit-energy pulses in your simulation. That might affect the result...

Comment: I think Engineer identified the issue in that the first Walsh code is all ones while the remaining codes are balanced. Does that make sense to you? It shouldn't matter if the pulses are unit-energy since that would simply scale the result. N x 0  = 0

Comment: How is the band-limiting realized or covered here?

Comment: Isn't every chip pulse-shaped? I'm thinking of each amplitude $a_m$ as a chip.

Comment: The signals are band-limited if $p(t)$ is band-limited (e.g. a raised cosine).

Comment: And yeah, the pulse energy shouldn't matter.

Comment: then that should be a convolution sum, not the sum as you show, right? (nvm-- I now see how the substitution is a convolution)

Comment: I must be missing something, so let's backtrack... My $a_m$ are real numbers. If the code has chips $-1,1,-1$ then the signal is $-p_0(t) + p_1(t) - p_2(t)$. I don't see the need for a convolution.

Comment: The convolution should be in the pulse shaping process since the tails of the pulses from adjacent symbols will overlap in time. But I think that is covered in your definition of $p_k(t)$ Each chip mapped to a pulse is offset in time and each pulse has a duration longer than a chip so appears to work out just fine.

Comment: Yeah, that should cover it. There is no requirement regarding the duration of $p(t)$ in my formulation.

Comment: So I think your answer is consistent with Engineer's conclusion in the other post-- if the orthogonal code has an equal positive negative density in its sequence then it will also be orthogonal with balanced pulse-shaping to other codes that are also equal in positive negative density. Do you concur?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm trying to reproduce your results with my own Matlab code. BTW, you're using square-root raised cosine pulses, right?

Comment: I guess I am not following that conclusion in your answer. I'm actually confused as you say $p_k(t)$ is an orthonormal set (and in the comments you say they are pulse shaped) and $a_m$ and $b_m$ are arbitrary real numbers-- but the question is how do we create $p_k(t)$?

Comment: no I was using raised cosine pulses. With roll-off factor = 0.3, oversampling factor of 10 and 10 symbol durations long (and then repeated with 20 symbol durations long).

Comment: Raised cosine pulses are not orthogonal, you need to use square-root RC.

Comment: Why is that? If you exclude the all 1's Walsh Code they appear to indeed be orthogonal consistent with your logic here.

Comment: Dan, I'm assuming $p(t)$ is a square-root raised cosine pulse, with a certain roll-off factor, and set up so that time-shifts of $kT$ result in orthogonal pulses. I just repeated your experiment with the Walsh codes and I get 0.0024 correlation between the first and the fourth rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105893/discussion-between-mbaz-and-dan-boschen).

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience in 802.11ad/11ay standard, I tried to check whether Golay codes used in this standard satisfy this criterion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Golay_code

The binary golay sequences comprising of +/-1 are used in the 802.11ad/ay standard for preamble transmission as well as spreading. The 32 and 64  length golay sequence are listed below in the MATLAB code used for simulation. The 32-length as well as 64-length sequences are orthogonal as is their upsampled-by-4 sequences (the dot product of root-raised-cosine filtered sequences)

```
clc
close all
clear all

codes1 = [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1];
codes2 = [+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1];
%codes1 = [+1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1];
%codes2 = [-1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1];

codes1_ups = upsample(codes1,4);
codes2_ups = upsample(codes2,4);

gt = rcosdesign(0.25, 20, 4);

tx1 = conv(codes1_ups, gt);
tx2 = conv(codes2_ups, gt);

sum(tx1.*tx2)

N = length(tx1);
plot(1:N,tx1,1:N,tx2)
```

[image]

(The second half of image are having same value for both sequences so they are overlapping).

***Dot product of root-raised-cosine filtered 32-length sequence = -0.0129.***

***Dot product of root-raised-cosine filtered 64-length sequence = 2.3726e-04.***

Like Dan's linked question, these are only 2 sequences of length 32 or 64. I will try if I come across codes having 4 or more orthogonal symbols (like the Hadamard sequence).

Comment: I am curious if there are any “pure” solutions that mathematically result in 0 such as completely synchronized Walsh codes.

Comment: I understand. I missed the word "complete orthogonality" in the question.

Comment: But still if that proves not to exist the solution that has the lowest cross correlation between all codes of a complete set will be selected as the best answer